# Accessing Codeigniter folder inside Wordpress directory

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I have installed Codeigniter into a directory called /portal inside my Wordpress directory. If I visit www.mydomain.com/portal I can see my default controller/view, which is a login page, however if I try to login I get a 404 error in the console for www.mydomain.com/auth/login.

Here's my Wordpress .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portal [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And my Codeigniter main .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Send request via index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I get this to work?

Codeigniter 3, Wordpress 4.6.3, PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a question mark after the index.php like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

So the full thing (in your CodeIgniter .htaccess file is like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) wordpress .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

2) Codeigniter .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

3) And Changed in your config file i.e  portal/application/config/config.php -  $config['base_url']

```
$config['base_url'] = '/portal';
```

It's work for me, you will try this.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Again, I can see the front controller and view but I cannot get past that. here's the domain. http://www.thegoldsquare.com/portal/ Try to login with any values.

Comment: If you look at the javascript console you'll see that it is returning a 404 error, but my controller is auth and I have a public method login, so portal/auth/login is correct... also I have this same code running on a different domain in the /portal directory just fine. That one just has no Wordpress.